# Как правильно: "на ветру́" или "на ве́тре"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, существительные

Как правильно: температура измеряется НА ВЕТРУ или НА ВЕТРЕ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: По-моему, оба варианта неправильны. И дело не в окончаниях. Не могу уловить связь между температурой и ветром. А что, в безветренную погоду эта температура измеряться не будет?

Comment: @grizzly: _ Что, по-Вашему неправильно в следующей цитате из научной статьи_... === Ну, если контекст у Никиты предполагался примерно такой, что Вы привели... Тогда, наверное, "измеряется на ветру"  возможно. Хотя "измерения [температуры] производят" для такого случая смотрится, на мой взгляд, значительно лучше.

Answer (score 4):

[**ве́тер**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%E2%E5%F2%E5%F0)
ве́тер, ве́тра, *предл.* **на ветру́**, *мн.* ве́тры, -ов и ветра́, -о́в (орфографический словарь);
ВЕТЕР, -тра (-тру), ***предлож.*** о ве́тре, **на ветру́** (большой толковый словарь).

Если используется предлог **НА** (где?) в предложном падеже, нужно применить т. н. местный падеж. В этом случае правильно не "на ветре", а [**на ветру́**](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80).

Слова, написанные на ветру; пепел на ветру; на ветру качаются ромашки; **температура измеряется на ветру**.

*В пятнадцать лет, **продутый на ветру**

Газетных и товарищеских мнений,

Я думал: «Окажись, что я не гений, —

Я в тот же миг от ужаса умру!..»*
Леонид Филатов

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае (смысл: в условиях ветра) правильно "**на ветру**", посколько ветер указывается в значении **процесса**, в условиях которого что-то делается или находится. В более редких случаях, если **ветер** употребляется в значении *объекта* или в *отвлечённом/абстрактном смысле*, может потребоваться выражение "**на ветре**":

> Верхом на ветр**е** (книга А. Беляева)
>
> Штурман прокладывал курс, основываясь на ветр**е** - на его силе
> и направлении.
>
> Движущая сила парусника основывается на ветр**е**.

Answer (score 0):

Многие слова мужского рода (неодушевлённые существительные), относящиеся к исконной лексике и имеющие одну гласную либо беглую гласную в корне, получают разные окончания в предложном падеже (для предложного-темы и предложного-местного соответственно).

Во втором случае (предложный-[локатив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6)) окончание становится безударным у.

> ветер - о ветре - на ветру
>
> сад - о саде - в саду
>
> лоб - о лбе - во лбу
>
> нос - о носе - в носу
>
> глаз - о глазе - в глазу
>
> род - о роде - в роду
>
> зоб - о зобе - в зобу
>
> кон - о коне - на кону
>
> круг - о круге - в кругу
>
> гроб - о гробе - в гробу
>
> край - о крае - в краю

Исключения:

> сон - о сне - во сне
>
> крик - о крике - в крике
>
> зов - о зове - в зове
>
> зуб - о зубе - в зубе
>
> рок - о роке - на роке
>
> крест - о кресте - на кресте
>
> дом - о доме - в доме
>
> конь - о коне - на коне
>
> пёс - о псе - на псе
>
> муж - о муже - на муже

...и так далее.

Возможно, различие объясняется употребимостью первых слов (с различным окончанием для предложного-локатива) и в разговорной речи, в то время как существительные из второй группы - в книжной церковнославянской, либо большей архаичностью слов из первой группы.

Answer (score 0):

**Температура измеряется не ветру.** А еще лучше: **температура измеряется с учетом ветра.**

Об охлаждающем эффекте ветра: http://tehtab.ru/Guide/GuideTricks/WindChillingEffect/

**Примечание**

**Сейчас всё происходит на ветру,** но еще совсем недавно падежная форм ***на ветре*** также применялась (прежде всего, парусные корабли ходили на ветре):

**Примеры:**

...я нашёл иней на низменных местах островов реки, хотя возле нашей палатки **(на ветре) термометр на рассвете показывал +9°.** [Н. М. Пржевальский. От Кульджи за Тянь-Шань и на Лоб-Нор (1870)]

Он ... ловко закурил **на ветре папироску.** [К. М. Станюкович. Ледяной шторм (1900)]

Туго расправились **на ветре паруса.**  [Б. С. Житков. Черные паруса (1930)]

...весь день мотается, **как мочалка на ветре,** и не находит времени даже погулять в лесу. [М. М. Пришвин. Дневники (1922)]

В 2 часа ночи увидели под ветром льдяной остров; с теми парусами, которые мы имели, я не надеялся **пройти на ветре** оного, и потому обошел **под ветром.** [Ф. Ф. Беллинсгаузен. (1831)]

Comment: Jasmin: _А еще лучше: **температура измеряется с учетом ветра**._ === А это как?

Comment: Это по ссылке можно посмотреть. А вот как она измеряется на ветру - непонятно (ветер  или есть, или его нет).

Comment: Jasmin: _Это по ссылке можно посмотреть._ === По-моему, нельзя. В Вашей ссылке речь идёт об "ощущаемой" человеком температуре (может, я неправ?). А каким прибором можно **измерить** "ощущение"?

Comment: Ну, это не вопрос для современной науки, хотя подробности мне неизвестны. Но вот Яндекс, например, сообщает: температура 20 градусов, ощущается как 22. Спросите у Яндекса.

Comment: Jasmin: _...Спросите у Яндекса._ === Но ведь это же не Яндекс написал "температура **измеряется** с учетом ветра", а Вы!